# How to jump forward if current PC = 0xFFFFFF00?

Tags: assembly, mips

How to jump forward if current PC = 0xFFFFFF00? I'm talking about the j instruction here.

I have no idea how to advance beyond 0xFFFFFF00, that's the last slot in the memory address right?

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFC would be the last address for an instruction.  If it is the defer slot of a branch then the branch would be 0xFFFFFFF8.  Just going on address numbers, I dont know if the mips architecture you are using has other limitations.  Some processors/systems allow you to roll over and the next instruction after 0xFFFFFFFC would be 0x00000000.

Comment: if branching forward then you could in theory branch from 0xFFFFFFF0 to 0xFFFFFFF8 with 0xFFFFFFF4 and 0xFFFFFFFC having instructions in the defer slots.

Comment: I don't understand how 0xFFFFFFFC can be the last address for an instruction since the instructions are word-aligned? There is always going to be a double zeros at the end of the instruction address right?

Comment: right 0xC = 0b1100 two zeros.  Or think of it another way, count by fours 0xF0 0xF4 0xF8 0xFC.  all word aligned addresses.

Comment: I see your confusion, it is two zeros in BINARY not HEX, your hex number ended with eight zeros.  0x00 = 0b00000000, eight zeros.

Comment: Omg. Thank you so much for pointing out my misunderstanding! Now I get what you're saying.